# OOP PHP require classes, extends

Tags: php, oop

Currently I am trying to understand how OOP applies to PHP and I am having trouble with calling my class when I am getting into inheritance.

I am using the following PHP code:

```
require_once("init.php");

$table = new Table();
$table->draw();

$customer1 = new Customer();
```

Since the table class is just a plain class (not inherited) it will load correctly.

The init.php has the following PHP code:

```
function __autoload($class_name) {
require_once('classes/'.$class_name . '.class.php');
}
```

Because the Customer class is inhereting the User class, the code for the Customer class is inside the User class, however the __autoload function is trying to call for the customer.class.php now.

My Customer class would look something like this:

```
class User
{
    private $_username;

    public function __construct($name)
    {
        $this->_username = $name;
    }

    public function getUsername()
    {
        return $this->_username;
    }
}

class Customer extends User
{
    public function __construct()
    {
        //some code here
    }
}
```

Cany anyone explain me please how I should call an inherited class with PHP?

Comment: `Because the Customer class is inhereting the User class, the code for the Customer class is inside the User class` doesn't make any sense.... what is the definition of your customer class?

Comment: `__autoload()` will run for any/all classes that PHP encounters that it has not seen defined anywhere, even if it's an inherited class.

Comment: An inherited class is a class like any other.  There's no difference in using it.  What's actually going wrong here?

Answer (score 2):

You should only have one class per file. Your autoload will handle everything for you as long as every class is in its own file, named the same way...

Put all your Customer class code inside Customer.class.php

Answer (score 2):

Each class should be written in its own file, exactly because of this autoload. There's no reason why `class Customer` must be within the same file as `class User`, just put it in its own file and your autoloader will handle it correctly.

Otherwise, you'll have to adopt some other naming scheme and write a more intelligent autoloader which can find classes in files with different names. (Don't do that, not really.)

Comment: Yes this was what I thought of doing, but does extends still work here then?

Comment: @Barrosy Yes, absolutely. The only requirement is that the `User` class is loaded/can be autoloaded when PHP hits the `extends User` statement; nothing dictates that the class must be in the same file. In fact, it's typical that you would be inheriting 3rd party library classes, whose files you're certainly not going to edit.

Comment: If it had to be in the same file you could never implement your own [iterator](http://docs.php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php), since you wouldn't be able to find the php script file that defines this interface ;-)